# Tuple returned from sql can't be converted to int

Tags: python, sql

i am trying to get the last value of the id  from the SQL table, but it returns tuple and i am struggling to concatenate to an int in order to pass the value to the other methods,

Example of the method:

```
def generateId(myConnection):
    with myConnection:
        cur = myConnection.cursor()
        cur.execute(" select max(id) from images")
        id = cur.fetchall()
    myConnection
    print id         # returns ((43L,),)
    newId = int(id) + 1


    return newId
```

The error:

```
<ipython-input-1-9955a4d0f492> in generateId(myConnection)
     30     myConnection
     31     print id
---> 32     newId = int(id) + 1
     33 
     34 

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

If you have any further questions regarding my database or method, please let me know, Thank you in advance

Comment: `tuple` = table record and hence cannot be converted. Please add the result of the print (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try assigning your id with following;

```
((id,),) = cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `cur.fetchone()` or you can use `int(id[0][0])`

Comment: If none of them work, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: With cur.fetchone(), you should get (43L,) and cur.fetchone()[0] should give you the id. (I thought you could figure that out, but anyways).. 
And, for the second option: if your id is ((43L,),) then id[0] should give you (43L,) and then id[0][0] should give you 43L which you then pass in int method to get 43

Answer (score 1):

.fetchall returns all (remaining) rows as a [sequence of sequences](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall). You can retrieve the first (and in your case, the only) row of the result with `cur.fetchone()[0]`. Consequently, the value in the first (again, also the only) field of the first row can be retrieved as `id = cur.fetchone()[0][0]`.